# How do I query Azure Data Lake Store

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-lake

Do I have to learn U-SQL to query data in ADLS? Or is there a way to query to using SQL.

Comment: Hi,if you think my answer helps you, could you mark it for answer?Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Yes,you have to learn U-SQL to work with Azure Data Lake Store or Azure Data Lake Analytics.

U-SQL is a Microsoft query language that combines a declarative SQL-like syntax with C# programming, enabling it to be used to process both structured and unstructured data in big data environments. Introduced in this [document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/u-sql-the-new-big-data-language-for-azure-data-lake/), U-SQL is part of Microsoft's Azure Data Lake Analytics cloud service, but it lets users run queries against multiple data stores in the Azure cloud.

If you familiar with sql, u-sql will be easy for you to start with.Please follow this [get-started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-u-sql-get-started) document to refer to some basic samples.

Comment: I get the impression that Data Lake Analytics is a dead product (last update is ages ago and it doesn't support Lake Gen2), and I'm guessing U-SQL is going that way as well.